# why not find model file in app folder and migration folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new with Laravel and I am starting a project. first I made model but I did not find it in `app` folder and in `database/migration` folder
this the command that i make model with.

```
php artisan make:model modelname -m
```

Comment: Did you receive a response from the command that the model and migration were created successfully?  e.g., `Model created successfully.
Created Migration: 2019_07_13_163935_create_modelname_table
`

Comment: Also, while this doesn't affect file creation, you might consider using studly case in your model names since that's standard practice e.g., `php artisan make:model ModelName -m`

Comment: Also, are you working on a local server, or a remote server?  If it's a remote server, you will need to download the files from the remote sever to have them appear in your IDE.

Comment: yes I received this message

Comment: I use local server, and I used Moldelname this format

Comment: Maybe you just need to refresh the file structure?  Have you checked to see if they are on the disk in your file manager.  You are running the command in your project root, correct?

Comment: yes I am running the command in my project root, how to refresh the file structure?

Comment: Would need to know a lot more about your setup and OS to give any specifics. I would try right clicking in the file structure and see if there is an option to refresh in your IDE.  You are even using an IDE?  Were you able to locate them in your OS File Manager?  What about navigating to the files directly in the console?

Comment: I am using mac ,i refreshed the folder but nothing change ,I am using visual studio code.how can i navigate to the file directly in console

Comment: I guess you don't actually have to navigate to the files, you can just list the files in the console using the following commands.  `ls app/*.php` will display all .php files in your app folder.  `ls database/migrations` to list all migrations.  See what's there.

Comment: After you ran the command did you see the message "**Model created successfully.**"?